# c program doesn't work with large arrays size

Tags: arrays, c, binary, binaryfiles

I have this code, i'm reading a binary .dat file

```
static unsigned long BufferSize = 6000;
int i=0;
FILE *ptr;
unsigned long buffer2[5000031];

ptr = fopen("data.dat,"rb");
if (!ptr){
    printf("Hubo un error al leer el archivo\n");
    exit(1);
}
const size_t fileSize = fread(&buffer2, sizeof(unsigned long), 5000031, ptr);

printf("File size = %ld bytes\n", fileSize);
printf("Size of each item in bytes = %d\n", sizeof(unsigned long));

while(!feof(ptr))
{            
    printf("%lu\n", buffer2[i]);
    if (buffer2[i]== 201830034){
        printf("\n\n\n SE ENCONTRO EL ROL \n\n %lu posicion: %d\n\n\n", buffer2[i], i+1);
        
    }
    i++;
}
fclose (ptr);
```

The file that i am working with have app 5.000.031 numbers, when i set BufferSize with bigs number, like the previous the program compiles, but the run fails and when use numbers like 50000 works "fine", any thoughts of what can be?

srry for my english, it's not my native languaje.

Comment: You blew the lid off your stack, or in other words, `buffer2` is just too big to fit on the stack. Use dynamic allocation with `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

Comment: `fopen("data.dat,"rb");`, you have missed close double quote for `"data.rb", which is causing the dis coloration of code.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you discovered the stack overflow! Not the site, the error.

Your stack has a limit of variables that you can declare inside functions. Try to keep this size below 1MiB to avoid this error on most devices. You can change this limit in some compilers and OS.

If you need more space, use static variables or dynamic allocated variables.

For instance:

```c
int main() {
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("data.dat", "rb");
    if (!fp){
        printf("Hubo un error al leer el archivo\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_t sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned long *buffer = malloc(sz);
    size_t ret = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned long), sz / sizeof(unsigned long), fp);
    fclose(fp);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Where is the stack limit normally 4 MiB?  On many Unix-like systems, the limit is 8 MiB, but on Windows systems, it is normally just 1 MiB.  That's not disputing your diagnosis "the array is too big for the stack" — that is undoubtedly the case.  The OP uses 5 million and crashes, but it OK at 50 thousand; that's a big gap.  I think they might be OK up to about 1 million entries on a 64-bit Unix-like machine (`sizeof(unsigned long) == 8`) or about 2 million entries on a 32-bit machine (`sizeof(unsigned long) == 4`).  Using either a static array or a dynamically allocated array is better.

Comment: You are right, I dont know why 4MiB was in my mind.

Comment: Ok I discovered, ARM32 is 4MiB, and I work a lot with embedded systems, so it is usually the target for me.

Comment: On Unix-like systems, the stack size is controlled via the `ulimit` command. Run `ulimit -a -H` to find the hard limits and `ulimit -a -S` to find the soft limits. On macOS and Linux, `-s` asks for the stack size (in KiB). An ordinary user can increase the limit up to the hard limit; `root` (or other appropriately privileged users) may be able to increase it further. On macOS, the default (soft) limit is 8192 KiB (8 MiB), but it can be increased to 65532 KiB (4 KiB shy of 64 MiB). It isn't actually a compiler property at all.  This applies to desktop or server machines; embedded is different.

Comment: In a program, the POSIX [`getrlimit()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html)
and `setrlimit()` calls control these values — but if you're going to create a monstrous array on the stack using `setrlimit()` to increase the limit, then you need to ensure you get to call `setrlimit()` _before_ you create the array.  (PS: Thanks for the info about embedded ARM32 — it's always useful to have facts for systems I don't normally work with.)

Comment: Aside: Better code would use `long sz = ftell(fp); if (sz < 0 || sz > SIZE_MAX) Handle_Error();`.